# How can i implement material design in android <5.0 os

Tags: android, material-design

Friends, i need materiel design responsive like in whatsapp new app material design in all android version.

- i am trying to implement material design in my application UI. its working fine in os 5.0 and 5.1.
- all component are displaying material in 5.0 and 5.1 but in lower version it all are display like normal button image and all. But in android other <5.0 os it is displaying like normal ui compnent.
- So can you please guide me that how can i implement material design in 5.0> os applicatoin.

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675384/how-to-create-an-api-for-shipping-extension-to-work-in-android-app

Answer (score 1):

Use the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat). It contains special themes and view components that will allow you to achieve a Material Design look in older platform versions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'" to your gradle dependencies
2. Whenever you are using Button, Textview use v7 view elements.